# Is there a way to search for a keyword in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a website and I need to get the seller info off the website but instead of listing the name of the seller it has the logo so I was going to try and scrape the whole image but upon closer inspection I noticed inside the same code as the image URL they have the actual title of the company as you can see in the picture below.  Is there a way to search though that line of HTML to get just the text between "title=" and d">" right now when I scrape it I get the whole image URL.

```
def parse(self, response):
        for game in response.css('div.card > div.row'):
            item = GameItem()
            item["Category"] = game.css("div.col-12.prod-cat a::text").get()
            item["Card_Name"]  = game.css("a.card-text::text").get()
            for buying_option in game.css('div.buying-options-table div.row:not(:first-child)'):
                item["Seller"] = buying_option.css("div.col-3.text-center.p-1 img").get()
                item["Condition"] = buying_option.css("div.col-3.text-center.p-1::text").get()
                item["Price"] = buying_option.css("div.col-2.text-center.p-1::text").get()
                yield item
```

[image: Screenshot of website]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element::attr(value`) selects element attributes. For example:
`a::attr('href')` selects `href` attribute of `a` element.
Try this selector to extract `title` value:

```
response.css('div.row.align-center.py-2.m-auto > div.col-3.text-center.p-1 > img::attr(title)').get()
```